# apache2 proxy balancer - passing server name

Tags: apache, proxy, internal-load-balancer

I'm using apache2 as a local proxy balancer between the web and a jboss machine.
i've used the following configuration:

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
        BalancerMember http://localhost:8080
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /test balancer://mycluster
```

if i call my machine with www.mymachine.com/test then the call is passed to JBoss, but in the request it seems that it was called with 'localhost'.

how can I make sure the correct server name is passed as well?

Aviad

Answer (score 0):

all i needed to do is to add:
ProxyPreserveHost On